# Get specific item from a match of select-string

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file. I am searching for a value using select-string.
I need to identify the returned value on a specific column
the $Line[Cui]

```
$sLine= New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable
$sText = @"
Vendorid,Cui,Data,iStaus,CashVat
404,20955366,2022-08-11,1,True
1025,15293910,2022-08-11,-1,False
2022,27684873,2022-08-11,2,True
3055,29195059,2022-08-11,3,False
"@;
$csvText= $sText | ConvertFrom-csv -Delimiter ','
$sLine = $csvText |Select-string -Pattern '15293910' -SimpleMatch -Encoding utf8
```

The found object looks like a hashtable

```
'=====Match is is======='
 $sLine
'=====Match was======='
```

The returned value is 
=====Match is is======= 
@{Vendorid=1025; Cui=15293910; Data=2022-08-11; iStaus=-1; CashVat=False} 
=====Match was=======

But there following code line does not return a value

```
'=====Get the desired value for the key======='
 $sLine['CashVat'].value
'================================='
```

Returns nothing in debug window

Also the the GetEnumerator does not return a key value pair

```
 $sLine.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
                          $message = '{0} is key {1} value' -f $_.key, $_.value
                          write-output $message
                         }
```

Just lists the <> 73 times which is equivalent to the lengths of $sLine variable
Looks like the $sLine is just a line of text and not in hashtable format

Comment: have you tried `$sLine.GetType()` to verify what type it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sLine` is not a hashtable but `MatchInfo` object reurned by `Select-String`.

The other thing sls does here, is converting every object in array to string representation (which looks like hashtable definition), and then matching the pattern to that string. So it'll also match curly braces, semicolons and property names in it.

But if you already converted csv text to array of objects, you could search it directly, no need to use select-string: `$csvText | Where-Object Cui -EQ '15293910'`

Or use select-string on raw csv: `$sls = $sText | Select-String '15293910'`
If you skip `-SimpleMatch`, you'll have captured text in MatchInfo: `$sls.Matches` (this applies to your original example, too).

Comment: I tried to extract the whole line and access other properties of the line.  However I switched to Where-Object and made a full search using multiple arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Where` selector.

```
$sLine = $csvText | where {$_.Cui -eq 15293910}
$sLine.CashVat
```

That will return `False`